# How to open url after BalloonTipClicked Event

Tags: c#, notifications, event-handling, notifyicon

How can i open an `url` after user clicked on `NotifyIcon`?

this is my code

```cs
public void ShowNotofication(string messages, string url)
{
    var notification = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon()
    {
        Visible = true,
        Icon = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information,
        // optional - BalloonTipIcon = System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon.Info,
        // optional - BalloonTipTitle = "My Title",
        BalloonTipText = messages,
    };
    notification.BalloonTipClicked += new EventHandler((sender, e) => OpenChrome(url));
    notification.ShowBalloonTip(5000);
}
public void OpenChrome(string url)
{
    Process process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe";
    process.StartInfo.Arguments = url + " --new-window";
    process.Start();
}
```

Notification are showed but `OpenChrome` method never called.

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to this:

```
notification.Click += new EventHandler((sender, e) => OpenChrome(url));
```

Instead of this:

```
notification.BalloonTipClicked += new EventHandler((sender, e) => OpenChrome(url));
```

Then the browser will open.